# How to turn a stable file to loop

Tags: animation, 3d-view, eevee-render-engine, loop

Just to be clear I'm total new and I'm using Blender.
In my first attempt I made a stable image and now i want my sea moving and a stable object to spin at the same time making a loop. If anyone could explain to me how I could do this I would be grateful!